# Make a batch file say something only when opened for the first time

Tags: batch-file

If it's possible, how do you get a batch file to only say something once? As in, only when it is opened for the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include this code wherever you want in your Batch file:

```
call :FirstTime 2>NUL
if errorlevel 1 (
   echo :FirstTime >> "%~F0"
   echo exit /B 0 >> "%~F0"

   echo This is the first time this file run!
)
```

Just BE SURE to end your Batch file with: `goto :EOF`

Comment: It doesn't do it only once. It does it twice. Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method - you can also add a path for the "firstrun.txt" file.

```
@echo off
if not exist "firstrun.txt" (
   echo This is the first time you have run this batch file...
   type nul >"firstrun.txt"
)

:: batch code goes here
```